# How to make contentprovider data available to all applications in android

Tags: android-contentprovider

i've used contentproviders with DB.it has some data in it.i need to make those data available to all other applications.How? Usually the main use of content provider is to store and retrieve data and make it accessible to all applications. They’re the only way to share data across applications; there’s no common storage area that all Android packages can access.I used the code from below link..

http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/custom-content-provider-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Distribute your Content URI and define your API.

Provide the string of your Content Authority and the paths you recognize.  Explain to your users how the tables in your DB map to your paths.  Document what the columns in your tables are.  Users with your content URI can read and write your databases using standard calls to ContentResolver and the insert/delete/update/query calls.

Provide access control in your `<provider>` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.  Look at [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html) especially with regard to `android:exported`, `android:grantUriPermissions`, `android:permission`, `android:readPermission` and `android:writePermission`.  You'll need to decide how to use those based on your use cases.  Also, the `<grant-uri-permission>` tag will give you even more fine-grained control.

Write other apps  to use those calls you just documented and allowed permissions for.